# Is it possible to use Proptypes for an associative array of complex objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Here is an example of the given structure I am looking for

```
const fields = {
  ["NAME"]: {isSet: false, display: "Customer Name", required: true},
  ["PHONE"]: {isSet: false, display: "Customer Phone", required: true},
  ["LOCATION_ID"]: {isSet: false, display: "Location ID", required: true},
  ["EMPLOYEE_ID"]: {isSet: false, display: "Employee ID", required: false},
  ["CUSTOMER_EMAIL"]: {isSet: false, display: "Customer Email", required: false},
  ["EMPLOYEE_EMAIL"]: {isSet: false, display: "Employee Email", required: false}
};
```

The key can be any string value and that value should be an object with `isSet, display, required`

Is this even possible or do I have to write a custom validator?

```
Header.propTypes = {
  fields: propTypes.arrayOf(propTypes.shape({
    ..... ?
  })).isRequired
};
```

Comment: Just a name thing to help you find answers in the future: "associative array" is not a thing in JavaScript. What you have there is an object. Arrays always have numeric indices, plus some other special semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note here is you can't use `PropTypes.arrayOf` since your structure is an object, not an array. You would need to use `PropTypes.shape`, but as you guessed, you can only do this with a custom validator.

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js#L419) for the shape validator, you'll see that it returns a function that loops over the keys of the object you pass it and runs the validator you passed along each key. Which is to say, you need to pass an object with explicit key names, which could be variables, but you can't give it a placeholder.

However, if your data structure was really an array, you could do the following:

```
Header.propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        isSet: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        display: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        required: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    )).isRequired
}
```

Otherwise you're going to have to write a custom validator, which is a function that receives `props`, `propName` and `componentName`, and returns an `Error` object if the prop you're given doesn't satisfy the condition you want.